# Can I use summernote html code to pass to jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, summernote

I'm trying to access value of summernote and try to pass it through ajax call but it is not calling the action of that controller.

log.cshtml

```
<div id="dvUpdate" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <form class="log-activity-form" id="addUpdate" name="addUpdate" novalidate>
                            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label class="control-label">Update</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <textarea rows="8" cols="150" class="summernote input-block-level" id="update" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;" type="submit"><strong>Save Update</strong></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

javascript

```
 $('#update').summernote({
        focus: true,
        height: 500,
    });

    $("#addUpdate").submit(function () {            
        var textareaValue = $('#summernote').summernote('code');           

        var activityData = { distance: "", distancetype: "", hours: "", minutes: "", seconds: "", activity: "Update", activityName: "", date: moment.utc(), notes: textareaValue };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "/Runner/CreateActivityLog",
            data: JSON.stringify(activityData),
            success: function (data) {
                //refresh feeds section                   
            }               
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I don't want to use razor syntax for form submit. I tried lots of combination to get the value of summernote, either it give object or null.

various ways i tried to get summernote code
 `var textareaValue = $('#summernote').code();
        var content = $('textarea[name="Update"]').html($('#summernote').code());
        var data = $('#summernote').summernote('code');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for reading the values from summernote we have to use

```
var textareaValue = $('#update').code();
```

this will give us html data we entered in summernote.

Answer (score 1):

$('#summernote') won't work. You are using summernote as a class so it would have to be $('.summernote').

I'm sure that summernote has to be applied to a div something like

```
<div id="summernote"></div>
```

and then you can use `$("#summernote").summernote('code')` to get your value.

Comment: Which version of Summernote are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.0.2 summernote version