# Data from summernote WYSIWYG editor always shows empty in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, summernote

I have initialised Summernot editor in my Laravel 9 app but it doesn't seem to send the data from summernote editor. I'm sending form data using ajax. It returns validation error as 'required' since the summernote data is required. When i check the console i see the 'data required' response and in the request tab you see that no data is being captured by the summernote editor despite typing in some data.

**Find below my code implementation**

```
@extends('backend.layout.general')

@section('title', 'Add Nutrition Item')

@section('styles')
    <!-- Dropify -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/css/dropify.min.css" integrity="sha512-EZSUkJWTjzDlspOoPSpUFR0o0Xy7jdzW//6qhUkoZ9c4StFkVsp9fbbd0O06p9ELS3H486m4wmrCELjza4JEog==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css') }}">
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <!--Internal  Sweet-Alert js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.4.24/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Dropify -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/js/dropify.min.js" integrity="sha512-8QFTrG0oeOiyWo/VM9Y8kgxdlCryqhIxVeRpWSezdRRAvarxVtwLnGroJgnVW9/XBRduxO/z1GblzPrMQoeuew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>}
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $('.dropify').dropify();

        // Summernote
        $('#description').summernote({
            height: 200,
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link']],
                ['view', ['help']]
            ]
        });
        $('#ingredients').summernote({
            height: 200,
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link']],
                ['view', ['help']]
            ]
        });
        $('#directions').summernote({
            height: 200,
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link']],
                ['view', ['help']]
            ]
        });


        if($("#createNutritionForm").length > 0) {
            $("#createNutritionForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    title: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    image: {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
                message: {
                    title: {
                        required: "Please Enter Nutrition Title",
                    },
                    image: {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    let myForm = document.getElementById('createNutritionForm');
                    let formData = new FormData(myForm);

                    

                    $("#createNutritionBtn").text('Please wait .....');
                    $("#createNutritionBtn").attr("disabled", true);

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('nutritions.store') }}",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            if(response.success) {
                                Swal.fire({
                                    position: 'top-end',
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    title: response.msg,
                                    timer: 1500
                                }).then(function() {
                                    window.location = "{{ route('nutritions.index') }}"
                                });
                            } else {
                                Swal.fire({
                                    position: 'top-end',
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    title: response.msg,
                                    timer: 1500
                                }).then(function() {
                                    window.location = "{{ route('nutritions.index') }}"
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            document.getElementById("createNutritionForm").reset();
                            $("#createNutritionBtn").text('Create Body Part');
                            $("#createNutritionBtn").attr("disabled", false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
@endsection


@section('content')
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Nutrition Items Management</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('nutritions.index') }}">Nutrition Items</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Add Nutrition Item</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="card card-primary">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Add Nutrition Item</h3>
                        </div>


                        <form id="createNutritionForm" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"
                                        placeholder="Enter Nutrition Item Title" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                                    <textarea class="description form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="description">Ingredients</label>
                                    <textarea class="ingredients form-control" id="ingredients" name="ingredients"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="description">Directions</label>
                                    <textarea class="directions form-control" id="directions" name="directions"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="category_id">Category</label>
                                            <select class="form-control select2" id="workout_intensity" name="workout_intensity" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                                <option selected="selected">Select Category</option>
                                                <option value="low">Low</option>
                                                <option value="moderate">Moderate</option>
                                                <option value="high">High</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="calories">Calories</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calories" name="calories"
                                                placeholder="Enter Calories" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="carbs">Carbs</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="carbs" name="carbs"
                                                placeholder="Enter the Carbs" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="protein">Protein</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="protein" name="protein"
                                                placeholder="Enter Protein" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="fat">Fat</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fat" name="fat"
                                                placeholder="Enter the Fat" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="servings">Servings</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="servings" name="servings"
                                                placeholder="Enter the Servings" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="total_time">Total Time</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_time" name="total_time"
                                                placeholder="Enter the Total Time" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="image">Nutrition Item Image</label>
                                            <input type="file" data-max-file-size="3M" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .webp, .png" class="dropify" id="image" name="image" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="featured">Featured</label><br/>
                                            <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" id="featured-y" name="featured" value="true">
                                                <label for="featured-y">Yes</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" id="featured-n" name="featured" value="false" checked>
                                                <label for="featured-n">No</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="status">Status</label><br/>
                                            <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" id="published" name="status" value="published" >
                                                <label for="published">Published</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" id="draft" name="status" value="draft" checked>
                                                <label for="draft">Draft</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <button type="submit" id="createNutritionBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add Nutrition Item</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title'             =>  'required',
            'description'       =>  'required',
            'ingredients'       =>  'required',
            'directions'        =>  'required',
            'category_id'       =>  'required',
            'calories'          =>  'required',
            'carbs'             =>  'required',
            'protein'           =>  'required',
            'fat'               =>  'required',
            'servings'          =>  'required',
            'total_time'        =>  'required',
            'featured'          =>  'required',
            'status'            =>  'required'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            // Upload an image file to cloudinary with one line of code
            $image = Cloudinary::upload($request->file('image')->getRealPath())->getSecurePath();

            
            $nutrition = Nutrition::create([
                'title'             =>  $request->title,
                'description'       =>  $request->description,
                'ingredients'       =>  $request->ingredients,
                'directions'        =>  $request->directions,
                'category_id'       =>  $request->category_id,
                'calories'          =>  $request->calories,
                'carbs'             =>  $request->carbs,
                'protein'           =>  $request->protein,
                'fat'               =>  $request->fat,
                'servings'          =>  $request->servings,
                'total_time'        =>  $request->total_time,
                'featured'          =>  $request->featured,
                'status'            =>  $request->status,
                'image'             =>  $image
            ]);
        }

        if($nutrition) {
            return response()->json([
                'success'       =>  true,
                'msg'           =>  'Nutrition Item added successfully!'
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success'       =>  false,
                'msg'           =>  'Something went wrong!'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Summernote is not a textarea and doesn't inject textarea value by default. to get data from summernote you can use [callback](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange).

```
$('#description').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
      console.log('onChange:', contents, $editable);
      $('#descriptionInput').val(contents)
    }
  }
});
```

and the HTML tag should be like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <div class="description form-control" id="description" ></div>
  <input id="descriptionInput" type="hidden" name="description"></input>
</div>
```

Another way is use put form input manually using `code()` method [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066586/can-i-use-summernote-html-code-to-pass-to-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: Yes, so i was able to get the value using `code()`.

Answer (score 0):

So i've been able to fix this issue by replacing the content of the formData.

`formData.set('name', 'value');`